# How to give shape to a CustomRadioButton in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to give shape to the CustomRadioButton in flutter?
as I found it has a property of customshape which will take boolean value. But I want to give a shape as per my requirement and also want that button should be filled with a color and icon. How will I do that? Please give me any suggestion!

[image: here is the image link]

Comment: Can you provide your radio button design?

Comment: @ rickimaru, I have shared it.

Comment: You can follow @Jay Dangar's advice. If you don't have any idea on how to do this. I can give you a sample code.

Comment: It would be my pleasure, if you can give @rickimaru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using custom radio button you can use two containers and give it a shape using boxdecorator and use custom listener for logic part by wrapping containers on InkWell and setting property onTap for logic.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the 1st answer. Here's a sample widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: GenderSwitch(
            onToggle: (Gender gender) {
              print('>>>>>>>>>> Gender = $gender');
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum Gender {
  MALE,
  FEMALE,
}

class GenderSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  GenderSwitch({
    @required this.onToggle,
    this.initialState = Gender.MALE,
    this.backgroundColor = Colors.black38,
    this.selectedColor = Colors.blue,
    this.selectedTextColor = Colors.white,
    this.unselectedTextColor = Colors.black87,
  });

  final ValueChanged<Gender> onToggle;
  final Gender initialState;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color selectedColor;
  final Color selectedTextColor;
  final Color unselectedTextColor;

  @override
  _GenderSwitch createState() => _GenderSwitch();
}

class _GenderSwitch extends State<GenderSwitch> {
  Gender _gender;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _gender = widget.initialState;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildButton(Gender.MALE, Icons.add, 'MALE'),
        const SizedBox(width: 10),
        _buildButton(Gender.FEMALE, Icons.ac_unit, 'FEMALE'),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildButton(
    Gender value,
    IconData icon,
    String text,
  ) =>
      FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() => _gender = value);
          widget.onToggle(value);
        },
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          side: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.black45,
            width: 1,
          ),
        ),
        color: _gender == value ? widget.selectedColor : null,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(icon),
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: _gender == value
                    ? widget.selectedTextColor
                    : widget.unselectedTextColor,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: @abhipsabiswal No probs. Good luck!